# WPF xml:lang/Language binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

how can i bind Listbox's or texblock's Language attribute (or xml:lang attribute).

i want to show month names in the specific language setting

ex:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Date" xml:lang="{Binding Lang}">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0:dd.MMM.yyyy}-{1:dd.MMM.yyyy}">
                <Binding Path="Date1"/>
                <Binding Path="Date2"/>
            </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

result should be according to Lang property:

01.Apr.2011 - 01.Apr.2011  en-US

or 01.Nis.2011 - 02.Nis.2011  tr-TR

or ....

it gives XamlParseException : Language attribute cannot convert to System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage type (that is not exact Error Text. )

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5):

In the `Startup` event of the application, add this instruction:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

It will override the default value of the `Language` property to the current culture, for the whole application.

---

EDIT: ok, I had misunderstood your question...

If you want to bind the `Language` property to a string containing the `IetfLanguageTag`, you need a converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(XmlLanguage))]
public class IetfTagToXmlLanguageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string tag = value as string;
        if (tag == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        return XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(tag);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        XmlLanguage lang = value as XmlLanguage;
        if (lang == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        return lang.IetfLanguageTag;
    }
}
```

Declare the converter in the XAML resources:

```
<local:IetfTagToXmlLanguageConverter x:Key="languageConverter" />
```

And use the converter in the binding:

```
<TextBlock Language="{Binding Lang, Converter={StaticResource languageConverter}}">
```

Comment: it is already overridden in StartUp. But i want to change all TextBlock Language property dynamically in the runtime. For Example; select a IetfLanguageTag value from a combobox. Thanks For the reply

Comment: i am going to try it in a 5 min. Thank you

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Did this work for you? When I tried it, I got an exception saying `Binding for property 'Language' cannot use the target element's Language for conversion; if a culture is required, ConverterCulture must be explicitly specified on the Binding`. Not sure what this means since the value for `Language` can be set and changed without any problems

Comment: This do not work, there comes a exception, like @FredrikHedblad wrote.

Answer (score 2):

you could create attached property and use it.

```
sealed class CultureBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty CultureProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Culture",
            typeof (string),
            typeof (CultureBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(OnCultureChanged));

    public static void SetCulture(FrameworkElement target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CultureProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetCulture(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        return (string) target.GetValue(CultureProperty);
    }

    private static void OnCultureChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = target as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null) return;

        element.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(args.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

XAML

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Utils"
....

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Repairs, StringFormat=c}"  local:CultureBehavior.Culture="{Binding CultureString}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Language can be bound to `CultureInfo` instance or `string` culture name.

To avoid error

> Binding for property 'Language' cannot use the target element's Language for conversion; if a culture is required, ConverterCulture must be explicitly specified on the Binding

set ConverterCulture for that binding as requested:

```
<Setter Property="Language" Value="{Binding CurrentUICulture.Name, Source={x:Static threading:Thread.CurrentThread}, ConverterCulture={x:Static globalization:CultureInfo.InvariantCulture}}"/>
```

( `Source={x:Static threading:Thread.CurrentThread}` is used as an example and should be removed if Language binds to property in the DataContext)