# Change culture of a value dynamically which is coming from property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have written code for changing the culture dynamically , it is working properly only for the strings that are coming as dynamic resource, but not for those strings which are binded to a property. Can anybody suggest here what to do?

My code for XAML:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
           Grid.Row="1" 
           Text="{Binding ServerInstanceName}" 
           Margin="0,0,16,24" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Here ServerInstanceName is written differently in English as compared to any other language. On changing language everything else is getting converted to the newer language but not the value of `ServerInstaneName`.

I have already tried :

[SO: Question WPF XAML Bindings and CurrentCulture Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display)

and this is not working as constructor in `xaml.cs` would not be called again when culture changes dynamically.

Also tried this:

[SO: How to display dynamic culture formatted number in a WPF UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152551/how-to-display-dynamic-culture-formatted-number-in-a-wpf-usercontrol?rq=1)

I can't reload module or the user control.

Comment: You should share your view model too.

Comment: Property in the view Model looks like:
public string ServerInstanceName
    {    get { return _serverInstanceName; }
         set
         {
           SetProperty(ref this._serverInstanceName, value);
           Profile.DbServerInstanceName = value;
           RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
           Profile.IsConnectButtonEnter = true;
         }
    }

Comment: "Culture of value"? If you want to change the text, you should set the ServerInstanceName property to whatever string you want to be displayed in the TextBlock.